# Show these affirmations using the context-free pumping lemma properties

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

**The question :**

Given $G$ a context-free grammar of Chomsky normal form with $k$ symbols. We know that the language $L(G)$ satisfy the pumping lemma for $ p = 2^k + 1$

I have those two questions to proove:

**1.** Show that for each word $w$ in $L(G)$ such as $|w| \geq p$, a word $w'$ exist in $L(G)$ such as $|w'|\lt|w|$
**EDIT THIS ONE IS ANSWERED ( SEE COMMENTS, 2 AND 3 LEFT)**

In other words, if a  word **w** exist in the language generated by the grammar that has a superior length than the pumping length then an other word **w'** exist and has a smaller length than **w** but is in the language.

**2.** Show that if $L(G) \neq \emptyset$ then a word x exist where $x$ is in $L(G)$ such as $|x| \leq p$

**3.** Show that this language is decidable $NV_{GNC}$ = {< G >: where G is a context-free grammar in Chomsky normal form and $L(G) \neq \emptyset $ }

This is my proof for 3 ( feel free to correct me if this doesn't work.)

If we have a grammar in Chomsky normal form, H, then it takes H exactly 2n − 1 steps
to generate an input of length n. (Unless n = 0, in which case it requires 1 step.) Thus, if G is
in Chomsky-normal form, we can design a turing machine that will generate all derivations in G
of length 2|w| − 1. Since there are finitely many rules, this can be done in finite time and space.
At that point, we only need to check all of our derivations against w; if any one matches, we
accept; if none do, we reject.

Note : to answer 2 you can use 1 and to answer 3 you can use 1,2.

I am really not sure what step i need to do to proove that, if anyone could help it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT for **1**: Apply the pumping lemma to $w$ and pump **down**; i.e., in [this version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages#Formal_statement) of the pumping lemma let $n=0$.

HINT for **2**: If not, let $w$ be a word in $L(G)$ of minimal length, and apply **1** to get a contradiction.

Comment: @codetime: Look at what you’re trying to prove in **1**: you’re trying to prove that something is true for **every** word of $L(G)$ with at least $p$ letters, so of course you can’t be given a particular $w$. But you know that of $|w|\ge p$, then $w$ can be decomposed into five segments, $w=uvxyz$, so that $|vy|\ge 1$, $|vxy|\le p$, and, most important for this problem, $uv^nxy^nz\in L(G)$ for **every** $n\ge 0$. What happens if you set $n=0$?

Comment: If n = 0 then i am left with $uxz$  and since $|uxy| \geq p$ we know that $|uxz|$ is smaller than p since  theres no more $y$ and so it prooves to us that $|w'|$ smaller than exists ? Is this right thanks

Comment: @codetime: No, $|vxy|\color{red}{\le}p$. We don’t know that $|uxz|<p$, but since $|vy|\ge 1$, we **do** know that $|vxy|<|w|$, which is all that matters.

Comment: Oh i see so if we remove vy then the length is at least smaller by 1 so we now have a w' smaller than w, but i am not sure why you compare $|vxy| \lt |w|$

Comment: @codetime: I didn’t compare $|vxy|$ with $|w|$; I pointed out that you were mistaken in saying that it was $\ge p$. (You had $uxy$, but that is clearly a mistake for $vxy$.)

Comment: Yes it was a syntax typo sorry, so the resume, to proove number 1. i can say : If n = 0 were left with uxz and since we know that $|vy| \geq 1$ we know that we have a w' that is smaller than w ( because of that 1 we removed). End of the proof. Is that correct thanks.

Comment: @codetime: Yes, that’s the argument for **1**.

Comment: For 2.  i am not sure about "apply 1 to get a contradiction" in one we found that for every w a w' smaller than w exists. And now we have to proove that a x such as $|x| leq p$ exist isnt that just one of the properties of pumping lemma  if n=0 $|uxy| \leq p$ ? Not sure to see the contradiction or make the link between both. Thanks.

Comment: @codetime: No, in **1** we found that if $w\in L(G)$ **and** $|w|\ge p$, then $L(G)$ contains a shorter word. Suppose that $L(G)$ contains no word whose length is $\le p$. Let $w$ be a word in $L(G)$ such that no word in $L(G)$ is shorter than $w$. (Why must such a word exist?) By hypothesis $|w|>p$. Now apply **1** to get a contradiction.

Comment: ohhhh it's a contradiction proof now it makes sens. And we know that such a word exists because from 1 theres always a word smaller than w, neccesarily we have a w a the top, not sure if i see it from the good eye, but there's a maximum |w| that we reach. Could you give me an insight on 3. ( i tried an answer) i think we don't need 1 and 2 for this one. Thanks you so much again.

Comment: @codetime: You need **2** for **3**: **2** tells you that if $L(G)\ne\varnothing$, then $L(G)$ has a word of length $\le p$. Thus, you need only generate all possible derivations of length at most $2p-1$, which you can do in finite time, and see whether any of them produces a terminal word.